# Game Maker Studio - Drawing Sprites from origin

Tags: game-maker

In a draw GUI event, I have placed,

```
draw_sprite(Sprite_HUD_Box,0,0,0)
```

When this is executed, the middle of the sprite, is placed at 0,0.  The origin of the sprite is its centre, so this was expected.  In the same event I also have

```
draw_sprite(Sprite_HUD_Box,0,view_hport[0],0)
```

To my understanding `view_hport[0]` is the length of the port, so should draw the sprite to the furthermost right of the screen.

The sprite is drawn at the end of the port, but instead of being drawn from the center, it is now drawn as if the x coordinate of the origin was 0.

How can I get the sprite to draw from the center as it did for the first line?

Also, I have,

```
draw_sprite_ext(Sprite_Fill,0,0,0,max(Object_Player.hp,1)/Object_Player.mxhp,1,0,c_white,1)
```

which draws from the centre, so as health in lost, it shrinks inwards.  I would like it to decrease from the right, and go towards the left until they run out of health.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

GUI event uses own sizes and position, it not depend on views and port. Usually this size equals of port size, but it may be different in lot of cases. You can change GUI size using `display_set_gui_size(width, height);` and for get size you can use `display_get_gui_width();` and `display_get_gui_height();`.

For get coords of the center of a sprite, you can use functions `sprite_get_xoffset(sprite)` and `sprite_get_yoffset(sprite)`.

Some examples, how you can draw sprite in different ways:

```
var spr = Sprite_HUD_Box;
var xoffset = sprite_get_xoffset(spr);
var yoffset = sprite_get_yoffset(spr);
var guiwidth = display_get_gui_width();
var guiheight = display_get_gui_height();

// Left top corner of the sprite at left top corner of the window
draw_sprite(spr, 0, xoffset, yoffset);

// Right top corner of the sprite at right top corner of the window
draw_sprite(spr, 0, guiwidth - sprite_get_width(spr) + xoffset, yoffset);

// Center of the sprite at left down corner of the window
draw_sprite(spr, 0, 0, gui_height);

...
etc
```

> which draws from the centre, so as health in lost, it shrinks inwards. I would like it to decrease from the right, and go towards the left until they run out of health. How can I achieve this?

Use `draw_sprite_part()` or  `draw_sprite_pos()` (it depend on what exactly you want).

Comment: I have used draw_sprite_part to draw a sprite, now I have also drawn another sprite with the exact same x and y coordinates but the sprite is not in the correct place (the one drawn with draw_sprite_part).  Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Share a small example with those two sprites.

Comment: draw_sprite(Sprite_HUD_Box,0,0+sprite_get_xoffset(Sprite_HUD_Box)+os,0+sprite_get_yoffset(Sprite_HUD_Box)+os)

Comment: draw_sprite_part(Sprite_HUD_Fill,0,0,0,sprite_get_width(Sprite_HUD_Fill) * (max(Object_Player.hp,1)/Object_Player.mxhp),sprite_get_height(Sprite_HUD_Fill),0+sprite_get_xoffset(Sprite_HUD_Box)+os,0+sprite_get_yoffset(Sprite_HUD_Box)+os)

Comment: No, I mean GMS project (I want see both - code and sprites). `File` -> `Export` and share it on dropbox/etc.

Comment: Just my sprites and code, or entire project?  I can add photos to the question, can't I?

Comment: I need see preferences of sprites (sprite size, position of the orign) and see code, how you draw them. Also room preferences, views prferences, gui preferences, used draw events, and other. Simplest way - just create a small **project** with these two sprites and drawing of them, and send it to me. I don't need your full project, I need a new small project with same problem (or make a copy of the project and delete all unnecessary things).

Comment: https://app.box.com/s/nhi68ga4pwbb3zrreuyu9142t1fuhg7w     I deleted all the sprites and objects and uploaded it.

Comment: Is [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78963719/stackoverflow/gml/Halp.gmz) what you wanted? (I disbled black background for see healthbars). P.S. As I wrote, for future: `File` -> `Export`, it's specially for share projects (all inside one file).